# Django: Use variable names instead of %s

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

Im passing multiple parameter into a raw sql statement, for each parameter im using %s
Is it possible to use the variable name instead of multiple %s

Example:

```
man = "John"
wife = "Jane"
query = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE name = %s and wife = %s"
cursor.execute(query, [man, wife])
```

Comment: I don't really get why it's related to Django if you're doing raw DB API

Answer (score 0):

Is it a model you are querying?

Looking at the docs explaining [the raw() manager](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries)

`raw() automatically maps fields in the query to fields on the model.`

this should be as easy as:

```
Person.objects.raw('SELECT id, first_name, last_name, birth_date FROM myapp_person')
```

Comment: The table I'm querying contains hundreds of thousands of rows. For efficiency id like to be more specific with my queries. Any ideas?

Comment: Also I'm working with a number of DB's some of which are not suitable for Django Models so i have querying the db directly

Answer (score 0):

DB API 2.0 defines following parameter styles

- `'qmark'`         Question mark style, 
                              e.g. `'...WHERE name=?'`
- `'numeric'`       Numeric, positional style, 
                              e.g. `'...WHERE name=:1'`
- `'named'`         Named style, 
                              e.g. `'...WHERE name=:name'`
- `'format'`        ANSI C printf format codes, 
                              e.g. `'...WHERE name=%s'`
- `'pyformat'`      Python extended format codes, 
                              e.g. `'...WHERE name=%(name)s'`

Now, not all databases implement all of them. Check if DB engine you're using does support `pyformat`.